# Intersecting a raster with a polygon using PostGIS - artefact error

Tags: raster, polygon, sql, spatial-database, postgis-2.0

I'm using [PostGIS2.0](http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-svn/using_raster.xml.html) to do some raster/polygon intersections. I'm having difficulty understanding which operation I should use, and what the quickest way of performing this is. My problem is as follows:

- I have a polygon and a raster
- I want to find all the pixels that fall within the polygon, and get the sum of the pixel value
- And (updated problem): I'm getting massive values for some pixels that do not exist in the original raster when I perform the query

I'm having difficulty understanding whether I should use `ST_Intersects()` or `ST_Intersection()`. I also don't know what the best approach for summing my pixels is. Here is the first approach that I have tried (#1):

```
SELECT 
    r.rast 
FROM
    raster as r, 
    polygon as p
WHERE
    ST_Intersects(r.rast, p.geom)
```

This returns a list of `rast` values, which I'm not sure what to do with. I tried calculating the summary statistics using `ST_SummaryStats()` but I'm not certain if this is the weighted-sum of all the pixels that lie within the polygon.

```
SELECT  
        (result).count,
        (result).sum    
FROM (  
         SELECT 
            ST_SummaryStats(r.rast) As result
         FROM
            raster As r, 
            polygon As p
         WHERE
            ST_Intersects(r.rast, p.geom)    
    ) As tmp
```

The other approach which I have tried (#2) uses `ST_Intersection()`:

```
 SELECT
        (gv).geom,         
        (gv).val
 FROM 
 (
    SELECT 
        ST_Intersection(r.rast, p.geom) AS gv
    FROM 
        raster as r, 
        polygon as p           
    WHERE 
        ST_Intersects(r.rast, p.geom)

      ) as foo;
```

This returns a list of geometries that I analyze further, but I assume this is less efficient.

I'm unclear on which is the quickest order of operation also. Should I always choose `raster, polygon` or `polygon, raster`, or convert the polygon into a raster so that it is `raster, raster` ?

EDIT: I updated approach #2 with some details from `R.K.`'s link.

Using approach #2, I have noticed the following error in the results which is part of the reason why I did not understand the output. Here is the image of my original raster, and an outline of the polygon that is being used to intersect it, overlaid on top:

[image]

And here is the result of the intersection using PostGIS:

[image]

The problem with the result is that there are values of 21474836 being returned, which are not in the original raster. I've no idea why this is occurring. I suspect it is related to small numbers somewhere (dividing by almost 0), but it returns the wrong result.

Comment: Regarding point two, you want to get the sum of the values of the pixels that intersect the polygon?

Comment: Yes, I have used `ST_SummaryStats()` for #1, but am not sure how to do it for #2.

Comment: Posted a link to a reference. I hope that helps.

Comment: My question has morphed a little from the original, but as it was so closely related I chose to leave them together. Hope this is ok.

Comment: The maximum value of the scale in your map is the maximum of a 32-bit signed integer. I do not know what that means in your case, but it could have to do with NA values. The range in your query might have null values that are not handled properly. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647#2147483647_in_computing

Comment: FWIW, 21474836 is *not* the maximum value of a 32 bit signed int.  However, 2^31-1 = 2147483647 *is* the max, and notice that 21474836 = 2147483647 / 100 (integer division).  This hints that internally some NA's are generated (perhaps along border cells), they are represented as 2^31-1, and then the code "forgets" these are NA and (perhaps in a resampling process?) it divides them by 100.

Answer (score 7):

I found a tutorial on [intersecting vector polygons with a large raster coverage using PostGIS WKT Raster](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/WKTRasterTutorial01). Might have the answers you're looking for.

The tutorial used two datasets, a point shape file  that was buffered to produce polygons and a series of 13 SRTM elevation rasters. There was a lot of steps in between but the query used to intersect the raster and vector looked like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE caribou_srtm_inter AS
 SELECT id, 
        (gv).geom AS the_geom, 
        (gv).val
 FROM (SELECT id, 
              ST_Intersection(rast, the_geom) AS gv
       FROM srtm_tiled,
            cariboupoint_buffers_wgs
       WHERE ST_Intersects(rast, the_geom)
      ) foo;
```

The values were then summarized using the following:

```
 CREATE TABLE result01 AS
 SELECT id, 
        sum(ST_Area(ST_Transform(the_geom, 32198)) * val) / 
        sum(ST_Area(ST_Transform(the_geom, 32198))) AS meanelev
 FROM caribou_srtm_inter
 GROUP BY id
 ORDER BY id;
```

I don't really know enough PostGIS to explain this but it sure sounds like what you were trying to accomplish. The tutorial should shed light on the intermediate steps. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks @R.K. I did read through that tutorial. I think my calculation is more basic, yet I'm still figuring out this basic step!

Answer (score 3):

With regard to point 2 in the original question - several of the postgis 2.0 development releases used a version of the GDAL library that cast floats to ints. If your raster has float values in it, and you were using a version of GDAL lower than 1.9.0, or a version of PostGIS 2.0 prerelease that didn't properly call GDALFPolygonize(), then you might be encountering this bug. Tickets in the [PostGIS](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/650) and [GDAL](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4005) bug trackers were filed and closed. This bug was active around the time of the original question.

In terms of performance, you'll find that using `ST_Intersects(raster, geom)` is much much faster than using `ST_Intersects(geom, raster)`. The first version rasterizes the geometry and does a raster-space intersection. The second version vectorizes the geometry and does a vector-space intersection, which can be far more expensive process.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having strange issues using `ST_SummaryStats` with `ST_Clip`. Querying the data differently told me the min value of my raster was 32, and then max 300, yet `ST_SummaryStats` was returning -32700 for the pixel values in my target polygon.

I ended up hacking around the issue as so:

```
WITH first AS (
   SELECT id, (ST_Intersection(geom, rast)).val
   FROM raster_table
   INNER JOIN vector_table ON ST_Intersects(rast, geom)
)
SELECT id, COUNT(val), SUM(val), AVG(val), stddev(val), MIN(val), MAX(val)
FROM first
GROUP BY id
```