# Performance in calculating raster statistics in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, intersection

I'm trying to calculate raster statistics (min, max, mean) for each polygon in a vector layer using PostgreSQL/PostGIS.

This GIS.SE answer describes how to do this, by calculating the intersection between the polygon and the raster and then calculating a weighted average: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/19858/12420

I'm using the following query (where `dem` is my raster, `topo_area_su_region` is my vector, and `toid` is a unique ID:

```
SELECT toid, Min((gv).val) As MinElevation, Max((gv).val) As MaxElevation, Sum(ST_Area((gv).geom) * (gv).val) / Sum(ST_Area((gv).geom)) as MeanElevation FROM (SELECT toid, ST_Intersection(rast, geom) AS gv FROM topo_area_su_region,dem WHERE ST_Intersects(rast, geom)) foo GROUP BY toid ORDER BY toid;
```

This works, but it's too slow. My vector layer has 2489k features, with each one taking around *90ms* to process - it would take *days* to process the entire layer. The speed of the calculation doesn't seem to be significantly improved if I only calculate the min and max (which avoids the calls to ST_Area).

If I do a similar calculation using Python (GDAL, NumPy and PIL) I can significantly reduce the amount of time it takes to process the data, if instead of vectorizing the raster (using ST_Intersection) I rasterize the vector. See code here: https://gist.github.com/snorfalorpagus/7320167

I don't really need a weighted average - a "if it touches, it's in" approach is good enough - and I'm reasonably sure this is what is slowing things down.

**Question**: Is there any way to get PostGIS to behave like this? i.e. to return the values of all the cells from the raster that a polygon touches, rather than the exact intersection.

I'm very new to PostgreSQL/PostGIS, so maybe there is something else I'm not doing right. I'm running PostgreSQL 9.3.1 and PostGIS 2.1 on Windows 7 (2.9GHz i7, 8GB RAM) and have tweaked the database config as suggested here: http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/tuning.html

[image]

Comment: I've edited my answer. I forgot to say that the intersection in my answer is less accurate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're right, using `ST_Intersection` slows down your query noticeable.

Instead of using `ST_Intersection` it is better to clip (`ST_Clip`) your raster with the polygons (your fields) and dump the result as polygons (`ST_DumpAsPolygons`). So every raster cell will be converted into a little polygon rectangle with distinct values.

For receiving min, max or mean from the dumps you can use the same statements.

This query should do the trick:

```
SELECT 
    toid,
    Min((gv).val) As MinElevation,
    Max((gv).val) As MaxElevation,
    Sum(ST_Area((gv).geom) * (gv).val) / Sum(ST_Area((gv).geom)) as MeanElevation
FROM (
    SELECT 
        toid,
        ST_DumpAsPolygons(ST_Clip(rast, 1, geom, true)) AS gv
    FROM topo_area_su_region,dem 
        WHERE ST_Intersects(rast, geom)) AS foo 
            GROUP BY toid 
            ORDER BY toid;
```

In the statement `ST_Clip` you define the raster, the raster band (=1), the polygon and if the [crop](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/RT_ST_Clip.html) should be TRUE or FALSE.

Besides you can use `avg((gv).val)` to calculate the mean value.

**EDIT**

The result of your approach is the more exact, but the slower one. The results of the combination of `ST_Clip` and `ST_DumpAsPolygons` are ignoring the raster cells that are intersecting with less than 50% (or 51%) of their size.

These two screen shots from a CORINE Land Use intersection show the difference. First picture with `ST_Intersection`, second one with `ST_Clip` and `ST_DumpAsPolygons`.

[image]

[image]