# Calculating mean value of polygon from raster in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql, raster2pgsql

I started with a NetCDF .gri and .grd raster file of the UK provided by a colleague. I clipped it in R to be only London, exported and converted to a ASC file, and then imported it to PostGIS using the following commands in R:

```
library(raster)
uk_raster <- raster("AnnMean2011.grd")
london_area <- extent(-720000.0,-630000.0,-50000.0,25000)
london_raster  <- crop(uk_raster, london_area)
writeRaster(london_raster, filename="AnnMean2011.asc", format="ascii")
```

And then on the Ubuntu command line:

```
raster2pgsql -I -C -s 10001 -t 20x20 AnnMean2011.asc annualmean | psql -d james_traffic
```

I now have a raster table in PostGIS. The SRID of 10001 is the following by the way, again, provided by a colleague:

```
INSERT INTO spatial_ref_sys(srid, auth_name, auth_srid, proj4text)
VALUES (10001,'CMAQ_Urban',10001,'+proj=lcc +a=6370000 +b=6370000 +lat_1=35 +lat_2=65 +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=000000 +y_0=00000');
```

In the same database I have a polygon file, SRID 27700, which covers London. I would like to calculate the average value within each polygon, from the raster.

I'm trying something like this, but it's not right:

```
select polygons.postcode, avg(st_value(joined_data.rast))
    from (
       select (ST_Intersection(raster.rast, 1, polygons.geom)).*
    from raster, polygons 
       where ST_Intersects(raster.rast, 1, polygons.geom)
  ) joined_data
group by polygons.postcode
```

How would I go about this please?

It seems to get the polygon and the raster aligned properly, I have to convert them both to WGS84 I think.

[image: Raster with Polygons, viewed in QGIS]

Comment: Note quite a duplicate, but your answer is probably here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083732/postgis-optimal-raster-tile-size-for-spatial-join-with-census-enumeration-distr

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks GIS-Jonathan, but I'm struggling to translate that into my dataset/situation. I'm trying something like this but it's not right (question edited above to include it)

Comment: If you still haven't got a solution, it may be worth asking on the PostGIS list.

Comment: I think this could be interesting for you: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76522/performance-in-calculating-raster-statistics-in-postgis/87781#87781. One exact but slow query in the question and a fast, less exact query in my answer. Further information also here: http://www.postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_SummaryStats.html (PostGIS Doc!!!). Literatur: PostGIS Cookbook. Paolo Corti et al.!!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from [Stefan](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/15459/stefan) yesterday, I think I can put something together from related questions and the official documentation and offer a range of solutions.

## [PostGIS documentation (`ST_SummaryStats`)](http://www.postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_SummaryStats.html)

#### Summarize pixels that intersect buildings of interest

This example took 574ms on PostGIS windows 64-bit with all of Boston Buildings and aerial Tiles (tiles each 150x150 pixels ~ 134,000 tiles), ~102,000 building records

```
WITH 
-- our features of interest
   feat AS (SELECT gid As building_id, geom_26986 As geom FROM buildings AS b 
    WHERE gid IN(100, 103,150)
   ),
-- clip band 2 of raster tiles to boundaries of builds
-- then get stats for these clipped regions
   b_stats AS
    (SELECT  building_id, (stats).*
FROM (SELECT building_id, ST_SummaryStats(ST_Clip(rast,2,geom)) As stats
    FROM aerials.boston
        INNER JOIN feat
    ON ST_Intersects(feat.geom,rast) 
 ) As foo
 )
-- finally summarize stats
SELECT building_id, SUM(count) As num_pixels
  , MIN(min) As min_pval
  , MAX(max) As max_pval
  , SUM(mean*count)/SUM(count) As avg_pval
    FROM b_stats
 WHERE count > 0
    GROUP BY building_id
    ORDER BY building_id;

 building_id | num_pixels | min_pval | max_pval |     avg_pval
-------------+------------+----------+----------+------------------
         100 |       1090 |        1 |      255 | 61.0697247706422
         103 |        655 |        7 |      182 | 70.5038167938931
         150 |        895 |        2 |      252 | 185.642458100559
```

## Avoiding `ST_Intersection` for performance

***Note that this is less exact, with intersecting pixels that cover less than 50% of an intersecting geometry being ignored.***

[Stefan](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/15459/stefan) has an answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76522/performance-in-calculating-raster-statistics-in-postgis/87781#87781) that avoids the `ST_Intersection`.

## Notes

- You might also find some useful tips in this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19856/intersecting-a-raster-with-a-polygon-using-postgis-artefact-error/19858#19858) and [PostGIS WKT raster tutorial](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/WKTRasterTutorial01).
- If your raster is tiled, a [good rule of thumb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24218654/3476750) is to use smaller tiles, trying to get them a little bit bigger than a typical vector feature that you're intersecting.

Comment: Is it possible to calculate raster statistics (mean value of crossed raster cells) along linestrings in a similar way?

Comment: I can't see why not, `ST_Intersects` will work the same with a linestring as a polygon.