# How to retrieve time-series aggregated data from rasters based on a polygon in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, raster, polygon, zonal-statistics

I created a database in PostGIS with some MODIS data stored in the **schema.table** `modis10v04.gpp`. A simple query to show the structure of my data is given as follows:

```
SELECT rid, filename, acquisition_range FROM modis10v04.gpp LIMIT 5;
```

My output is something like this:

[image: output from the SELECT query]

As you can see, there are repeated info in the first 4 rows, this is because of my rasters are divided in tiles. To clarify, my dates range from 2003-01-01 to 2016-12-31.

Then, I have my geometry data in the **schema.table** `public.shape10v04` containing polygons with the column "id".

What I want is the average of my data for each polygon (within my shape10v04) for each date (from initial date to final date, e.g. 2005-10-10 to 2007-10-10).

I came across the post referred here: 
[Calculate mean value of polygon from raster in PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155974/calculate-mean-value-of-polygon-from-raster-in-postgis), but it stills blurry in terms of implementing it for a time-series of rasters.

Comment: What have you tried. Those answers you link seem clear enough. Calculate area average by date, average across grouping by polygon

Comment: "Shapefile" is a file-based data format. It is **not** possible to have a shapefile in a database. Once loaded into the database, it becomes a **table**. It's not clear how this is "recurring" or what you want to accomplish. Please [edit] the question to specify your expected output.